# Search API view in not returning all results for full text search

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views, search

I have a search API indexed content view. Which uses full text search exposed filter. I have selected few taxonomy term names and other field in the full text search. But when I search for a term name, it returns only few results but not all. Please see the below image for the filter field.

[image]

Comment: have you tried running index? new contents needs to be index

Comment: @iamroald, Yes, I have tried the re-indexing. But the result was same.